# can't change the value of ONE button (search page SEARCH button)

Tags: 8, forms

I have succesfully changed the search button text of the block but can't seem to get to do this on the search page

on the following form_alter both forms enter it and are set but only `search_block_form` gets affected

```
function MODULE_NAME_form_alter(&$form, \Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface $form_state, $form_id) {
  if(in_array($form_id,["search_block_form","search_form"])) {
    $form['actions']['submit']['#value'] = "Custom Search Value";
  }
}
```

I have also tried doing it with `function hook_preprocess_input($vars){` and also tried to set the weight of the module to run later than others

```
function MODULE_NAME_install(){
  module_set_weight('MODULE_NAME', 1000);
}
```

but I see no difference I had to resolve this using javascript 
what am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

Did not realize the search page is structured different than a block search here is the solution that worked posting for anyone might have the same problem

```
function MODULE_NAME_form_alter(&$form, \Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface $form_state, $form_id) {
  if(in_array($form_id,["search_block_form"])) {
    $form['actions']['submit']['#value'] = "Custom Search Value";
  }
  elseif(in_array($form_id,["search_form"])) {
    $form['basic']['submit']['#value'] = "Custom Search Value";
  }
}
```